# Browse among outlook mails

Tags: python-3.x, email, outlook

I want to code a python soft that allow the user to browse among Outlook email and reply to them with templates.

I tryied to use pywin32.
I can send new mail, or see mails titles/ 
Objects, but i can’t really browse among them and reply to it.

Any idee of the library i can use ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: try this ones: imaplib for managing mails. smtplib for sending

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if i ´m right, i will have to code a full soft to manage the mails with these libraries. Is there any option to use outlook embeded in another soft or with api ?

Comment: actually, this is an 'api' some way. outlook is a simple visualized for mails. also, these libriaries give enough tools to maniulate mails. Didnt get the question. what do you mean "embeded in another soft or with api"?

Comment: I thought i was possible to launch outlook as a part of my soft, to use its options, views etc. Maybe plug to it.